# IabHelper (class) Dispose (method) unhandled exception

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement in-app purchase in my latest android project.
To do so, I'm following this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html).
Everything went smooth until I used the `dispose` method in order to close any communication with the play store.
What I get is the following error:

> Error:(101, 45) error: unreported exception IabAsyncInProgressException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

On the following code segment:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //Always unbind the with the store connection, otherwise performance degradation of the device may follow.
        if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }
```

After digging in the IabHelper class (Java) I found the `dispose` method.
Here the code of the method:

```
    /**
     * Dispose of object, releasing resources. It's very important to call this
     * method when you are done with this object. It will release any resources
     * used by it such as service connections. Naturally, once the object is
     * disposed of, it can't be used again.
     */
    public void dispose() throws IabAsyncInProgressException {
        synchronized (mAsyncInProgressLock) {
            if (mAsyncInProgress) {
                throw new IabAsyncInProgressException("Can't dispose because an async operation " +
                    "(" + mAsyncOperation + ") is in progress.");
            }
        }
        logDebug("Disposing.");
        mSetupDone = false;
        if (mServiceConn != null) {
            logDebug("Unbinding from service.");
            if (mContext != null) mContext.unbindService(mServiceConn);
        }
        mDisposed = true;
        mContext = null;
        mServiceConn = null;
        mService = null;
        mPurchaseListener = null;
    }
```

What should I do to resolve this error?
I understand that I should catch and exception but I am not confident enough to change by myself this method in this class.

(Thanks for any help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more research I've found that this question was already asked and answered.
Unfortunately the question is still marked as not answered.
Here there is the [link to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027885/in-app-billing-mhelper-dispose-error).

The solution is simple:

1. The file that you can get from the guide are outdated, and should be instead downloaded from [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive).
2. In the method `onDestroy` you should instead use the following code:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      //Always unbind the connection with the store, otherwise performance degradation of the device may follow.
      if (mHelper != null) {
         mHelper.disposeWhenFinished();
         mHelper = null;
      }
   }
   ```

`disposeWhenFinished` it's a more elegant solution that works better than a `dispose`.